# How Can I display my Navbar Dynamically with this amount of data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**I don't how to do looping on HTML using this data**

**NAVITEMS Data is saved in this 4D array its huge array I have copied some part of it**

```
const Navitems = [
{type: 'Mobile'},

  [{company: 'Acer'},
    [{series: 'ICONIA A-SERIES'} , 
      [{model: 'A1-810'},{model: 'A1-830'},{model: 'A1-840'}], 
    {series: 'ICONIA B-SERIES'}, 
      [{model: 'B1-710'},{model: 'B1-720'},{model: 'B1-730'}],
      {series: 'LIQUID'},
      [{model: 'A1-S100'},{model: 'Z200'},{model: 'Z500'},{model: 'Z525'}],
      {series: 'OTHERS'},
      [{model: 'W3-810'}]
  ],
  {company: 'Alcatel'},
    [{series: "ONE TOUCH"}, 
      [{model: '4037-Evolve 2'},{model: '4060-Ideal'},{model: '5020-Evolve'}],
      {series: "ONE TOUCH POP"},
      [{model: '4015-Pop C1'},{model: '4033-Pop C3'},{model: '5050 Pop-S3'}],
      {series: "SMARTPHONE"}, 
      [{model: '4013-Pixi 3 (4.0)'},{model: '5017-Pixi 3(4.5)'},{model: '5026-Alcatel 3C'}],
      {series: "ALCATEL TABLET"}, 
      [{model: '9002-Pixi 3 7 3G'},{model: '9007-Pixi 3 7'},{model: '9015-Pop 7 4G'}],
      {series: "BASIC PHONE"}, 
      [{model: '2017b-Fling'},{model: '4044-Go Flip'},{model: 'A392A'}]
    ]
],

{type: 'Computer Parts'},
  [{company: "Acer"},
    [{series: 'Aspire'}, 
      [{model: "5551"},{model: '5560'}]]
]

]
```

**I am reading this 4D array data using a function as follows**

```
   for(i=0 ; i < Navitems.length; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            console.log("Type ", Navitems[i].type);
        }
        else{
            for(var j=0; j < Navitems[i].length; j++){
                if(j%2 == 0){
                console.log("Company ", Navitems[i][j].company)
                }
                else{
                    for(var k=0; k< Navitems[i][j].length; k++ )
                    {
                        if(k%2 == 0){
                            console.log("Series ", Navitems[i][j][k].series )
                        }
                        else{
                            for(var l=0; l< Navitems[i][j][k].length; l++)
                            {
                                console.log("Model ", Navitems[i][j][k][l].model)
                            }
                            }
                    }
                    }
            }
            }
    }
```

**This is the HTML code of a single dropdown link. Now, I want to do looping in this HTML using the data from above. Which I can't understand**

```
     <div class="dropdown d-inline-block" id="Cellphone">
                <div id="type">
                <span class="dropdown-toggle" id="parts" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
      aria-expanded="false">CELLPHONE PARTS</span>
            </div>
                <div class=" dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="parts">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="width: 1000px; min-height: 400px;"> 
                    <div id="leftbar" class="d-flex flex-column" style="width: 250px; background- 
        color: rgba(228, 226, 226, 0.829);">
                    <div id="company">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Iphone / Ipad </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mac</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    </div>

                    </div>

                    <div id="rightbar" class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                        <div id="series">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-width: 250px;" >
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><h4>Iphone / Ipad</h4></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="model">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mac</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-width: 250px;" >
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><h4>Iphone / Ipad</h4></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mac</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-width: 250px;" >
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><h4>Iphone / Ipad</h4></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mac</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-width: 250px;" >
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><h4>Iphone / Ipad</h4></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mac</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Samsung</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                </div>
                    
                  </div>
            </div>
```

**It should look like this**
[image: This image is a screenshot of what this data should look like]

Comment: You should use a web framework like svelte, react or do it manually by generating html elements

Comment: I have to do it in HTML using mapping or using loop in the script tag or using insertAdjacentHTML() function. but I have to do it in HTML.

Comment: @carsten-løvbo-andersen any idea sir?

Comment: @peter Sir any idea?

Comment: @danny-365csi-engelman